# Remember + relative clause + doing something

Tags: grammar, relative-clauses

I just saw a sentence in the Cambridge Dictionary:

> I remember **when I was a child** *being very impressed with how many toys she had.*

I as a learner would write it as:

> I remember being very impressed with how many toys she had when I was a a child. (Structure: **remember doing something**)

Is there any rule to write the *relative clause* in the middle in this case?
Are they interchangeable?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The first version sounds more natural—although *and* could be added after *child*.

Comment: @JasonBassford is the second one grammartical?

Comment: They are both grammatical.